# Hapi js as proxy server to handle api calls

Tags: angular, hapi

Could someone please post an example of how to use *Hapi js* as proxy server to make *api* calls. Let's say I send a request to *www.example.com* to fetch the response. Currently I am making the *api* call directly from my *angular application* to www.example.com. Instead *hapi js* should act as proxy server, get the request and send the *request* to www.example.com, fetch the *response* back and give it to my angular application.

Answer (score 0):

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = {
  "*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:9000", // your server address
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "bypass": function (req, res, proxyOptions) {
      /* Fix for angular route refresh causes Not Found Error. For a browser requests, we want to serve a HTML page, but for an API request we want to proxy it.*/

      if (req.headers.accept && req.headers.accept.indexOf("html") !== -1) {
        console.log("Skipping proxy for browser request header ==> " + req.headers.accept);
        return "/index.html";
      }
    }
  }
}

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

you have  to handle like  this from angular for connecting server

Comment: Where should we use this? Is it where we are starting the hapi server?